# How to normalize noisy data?

Tags: probability, statistics, data-analysis

I'm a computer science student and for a project I'm taking sensor data and normalizing it into a 0 - 255 range. Problem is when I get the data I don't know the minimum and maximum (it varies very widely based on where the sensor is located) and that really affects how normalizing the data goes. I would just find the min and max in the data set but it's noisy enough outliers screw this up. This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tat1a.jpg) isn't my data, but the graph looks similar.

My question is how to find a reasonable minimum and maximum to normalize against. I was thinking about finding the average minimum (average of all the lows) and average maximum (average of all the highs) and using those, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that in an efficient way. Currently I'm graphing the data in excel and deciding a reasonable minimum and maximum but that isn't feasible in the long term. For the graph I linked, I would probably use a min of 190 and a max of 270 to normalize it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing

Comment: I don't see that this plot is very noisy (about 5% amplitude) so it is hard to understand what you need.

Comment: Do you have a histogram of the data?  It seems like you spend enough time near the minima and maxima that [Tukey's fences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Tukey%27s_fences) aren't great.

Comment: You could use a median filter with a suitably chosen window size.